# Getting "NoneType object is not subscriptable" while scraping the 'aria-label' content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, data-science

I am scraping a website using BeautifulSoup4 that has the content under it's `aria-label` tag. I have condensed down my hierarchy to a single tag but when I am trying to extract the data from it, it gives me this error: `"TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable"`

A variable right_elem gives me the list of all the tags I am interested in:

```
right_elem = change_script[41].findAll("circle")
```

and the following is one of the tags I am interested:

```
<circle aria-label="Filling capacity of the engine is 24 liters" class="graph-bullet" cx="0" cy="0" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" r="4" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(4,177)"></circle>
```

I have tried the following so far to overcome this issue but found no success:

```
- right_elem[0].select_one('[class*="graph-bullet"][aria-label]')['aria-label']
- right_elem[0].find("circle", class_="graph-bullet")["aria-label"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `right_elem[0].find(...)` That's only searching the _first_ element in the list, yes?  What if the desired element isn't first?

Comment: @JohnGordon tried using findAll as well. It returns "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`right_elem[0].find("circle", attrs={'class': 'graph-bullet'}).attrs["aria-label"]`

Cause when you use `right_elem[0].find("circle", class_="graph-bullet")` you just get 
HTML Parsing (Soup Object). And when you call `.attrs` it will return a dictionary of all attributes. Then you subscript it by `["aria-label"]`.
Hope it will work.

Comment: It gives me this error: "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'attrs'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

Comment: yup, sorry, its must be find =)))

Comment: Tried that as well: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'"

Comment: So, which mean there is no any `circle` tags in this `right_elem[0]`.

Comment: But again, `right_elem[0]` gives me `<circle aria-label="Filling capacity of the engine is 24 liters" class="graph-bullet" cx="0" cy="0" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" r="4" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(4,177)"></circle>`

Comment: okay, so `right_elem[0]` that the final result you need to find. Remember, `find()` or `find_all()` methods that will find **inside** (`children` tags)`soup` object. As you can see, there is no any tag (or `circle` tags - for more specific) **inside** `right_elem[0]`.

So as this. You must use this code `right_elem[0].attrs["aria-label"]`. Again, hope this will work~~